# OAuth2 auth on postman when token at hand

Tags: oauth-2.0, soapui, postman

How to configure postman when you already have a token/bearer key at hand?

Was hoping it would be somewhat similar with seting up an OAuth2.0 authentication with SoapUI that you can just input the bearer/token key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an access token, you can configure POSTman by setting up a custom Authorization header.  Setup:

```
Authorization: Bearer <accessToken>
```

And if the API you are accessing supports bearer tokens, and you are providing a valid access token, then it should work.

Comment: Tried to add a custom **Authorization** header with this value **Bearer: <token>** and still not passing through

Comment: There is no colon after "Bearer" - in my example, the colon is just a convention for separating the header name from the value - the value should just be **Bearer <token>**